# Angular2 - 404 GET /app/app.component.js

Tags: angular

I downloaded Angular2 Quick Start from GitHub [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart). I moved all configuration files to config directory to keep my project organized. therefore; I ran into an issue **"404 GET /app/app.component.js"** as shown below.

So, my project looks like:

- Project_Name
- App

  - app.component.ts
  - main.ts
- config

  - includes all configurations files (tsconfig, typings, package, etc..)

**# Sample of output**

16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /main.js
16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic//bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
**16.06.25 19:08:55 404 GET /app/app.component.js**
16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common//bundles/common.umd.js
[1](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) 16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js
16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js
16.06.25 19:08:55 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser//bundles/platform-browser.umd.js

**# Main.ts**

```js
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from "app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**# app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker for the same..

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing
import {AppComponent} from "app.component";

to

> import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";